# My Media query in CSS is not switching containers

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to get my css media query to toggle between smartphone and desktop display for a Tableau visualization.

### I wrote this code, and its not working. Can somebody please help? (The two large chunks below are embed codes for my two vizzes customised for phone and desktop.)

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>


    @media only screen and (max-width:433px){
    Phone {
    height: 733px;
    width: 433px; 
      } 
   }

    @media only screen and (max-width:1500px) {

   Desktop {
    height: 864px;
    width: 1016px; 
     } 
  }

  </style>
   </head>

  <body>

  <div class=‘Phone’ id='viz1496071997211' style='position: relative'>
    <noscript><a href='#'><img alt='Indian Mutual Fund Industry: From Sensex
    20,000 to 30,000' src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com
     &#47;static&#47;images&#47; In&#47;IndianMFindustrySmartphoneDashboards
    _0&#47;
   Story1&#47;1_rss.png' style='border: none' /</a></noscript><object   class='tableauViz'  style
   ='display:none;'>
   <param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' />    <param name='site_root' value='' /><param name='name'    value='IndianMFindustrySmartphoneDashboards_0&#47;Story1' />
   <param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
  <param name='static_image'   value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;
images&#47;In&#47;IndianMFindustrySmartphoneDashboards_0&#47;
Story1&#47;1.png'    /> <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' />
 <param name='display_static_image' value='yes' />
  <param name='display_spinner' value='yes' />
  <param name='display_overlay' value='yes' />
  <param name='display_count' value='yes' /></object></div>
                        <script type='text/javascript'>                   
   var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1496071997211');                    
    var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];                 vizElement.style.width='437px';vizElement.style.height='802px';                        var scriptElement = 
       document.createElement('script'); scriptElement.src=     'https://public.tableau.com/
          javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                      vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore
              (scriptElement, vizElement);                     </script>


    <div class=‘Desktop’ id='viz1496070740402' style='position: relative
     <noscript><a href='#'><img alt='Indian Mutual Fund Industry: From Sensex 20,000 to 30,000 ' 
     src='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;
  static&#47;images&#47;Mu&#47;MutualFUndIndustry&#47;MainStory&#47;1_rss.png'        style='border: none' /></a>
       </noscript><object class='tableauViz'  
       style='display:none;'><param name='host_url'          value='https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F' /> 
            <param name='site_root' value='' /><param name='name'    value='MutualFUndIndustry&#47;MainStory' />
  <param name='tabs' value='no' />
   <param name='toolbar' value='no' />
   <param name='static_image'   value='https:&#47;&#47;public.tableau.com&#47;static&#47;images&#47;Mu&#47;MutualF      UndIndustry&#47;MainStory&#47;1.png' /> 
         <param name='animate_transition' value='yes' />
         <param name='display_static_image' value='yes' /><param     
        name='display_spinner' value='yes' />
          <param name='display_overlay' value='yes' /><param 
          name='display_count'     value='yes' /></object></div>               
          <script type='text/javascript'>                    
         var divElement = document.getElementById('viz1496070740402');                      
         var vizElement = divElement.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];              
         vizElement.style.width='1020px';vizElement.style.height='933px';                       
         var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');                    
        scriptElement.src   
         ='https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js';                    
         vizElement.parentNode.insertBefore(scriptElement, vizElement);                
         </script>
          </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you have fancy quotes in your markup and your css selectors need to be `.Phone` and `.Desktop` with the `.` at the beginning to denote you're selecting a class.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using classes in css then add . before classname and if you are using ids in css then add # before id

and your code in html includes different quotes, try to use ('' and "") in your code

example from your code:

```
.Phone {
height: 733px;
width: 433px;
}
.Desktop {
height: 864px;
width: 1016px;
}
```

Comment: I added the dots. It still won't give me separate displays for phone and desktop.

Comment: if you are adding right quotes then your code must code, and @media only screen and (max-width:1500px) rule means your Desktop class div will be visible in mobile also.